# Find a threshold such that one function is always bigger than the other

Tags: recursion, proof-assistants

Given the recursively defined function  $c$:
$$c(m,n)=\begin{cases}0&\text{for }m=0\\
n^2+n+1&\text{for }m = 1\text{ and }n\ge 0\\
c(m-1, 1)&\text{for }m>1\text{ and }n=0\\
c(m-1,c(m,n-1))&\text{for }m>1\text{ and }n>0\\
\end{cases}$$

and the function $d$:

$$d(n) = \underbrace{2^{2^{.^{.^{.^{.^{2}}}}}}}_{\text{$n+2$ }}$$

The inputs $m$ and $n$ are both natural numbers. I'm asked to find an $x$, such that for all numbers $y \ge x$, $c(y,y) > d(y)$.

I rewrote the two functions using Python in order to calculate some values:

```
 c(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        return 0
    else if m == 1 and n >= 0:
        return n**2+n+1              # return n^2+n+1
    else if m > 1 and n == 0:
        return c(m-1, 1)
    else if m > 1 and n > 0:
        return c(m-1, c(m, n-1))
```

```
 d(n):
    exp_num = n-1
    result = 2
    while exp_num != -1:
        result = 2**result           # result = 2^result
        exp_num = exp_num - 1
    final_result = 2**result         # final_result = 2^result
    return final_result
```

Some inputs and outputs:

`c(1, 1) = 3`

`c(2, 2) = 183`

`d(1) = 16`

`d(2) = 65536`

`d(3) = 20035299... 19156736`, a number with 19729 digits.

I believe the threshold is $3$, as `c(3, 3)` doesn't seem to be realistically computable considering there are over 19K digit in [A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function)(4, 2). Unfortunately I have no idea how to prove this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look up the Ackermann function for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, the threshold is indeed 3.

Here is one approach to prove that for all numbers $y \ge 3$, $c(y,y) > d(y)$.

Step 0, show that $c(\cdot, \cdot)$ is strictly increasing with respect to each variable when the second variable is not 0.
Step 1, show that $c(1,n) \gt n^2$ for all $n\ge0$.
Step 2, show that $c(2,n) \gt 2^n$ for all $n\ge0$.
Step 3, show that $c(3,n)\gt d(n)$ for all $n\ge0$.
Step 4, show that $c(y,y) \gt d(y)\text{ if }y\ge3$.

---

**Exercise.** Show that $c(3,y) > \underbrace{2^{2^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^2}}}}}_{2y+2 \text{ copies of }2}$ for all $y\ge0$.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I could show that c is monotone increasing, but could you elaborate why 1, 2, 3 are necessary?

Comment: I also edited my Python implementation of ```d(n)```

Comment: "Could you elaborate why 1, 2, 3 are necessary?" I am not sure of what you were asking. They are just part of my approach to prove 3 is the threshold. Each of them can be proved by simple induction using what have been proved in previous steps.

Comment: I wasn't sure why we had prove the previous steps. Thank you, I will try to solve and get back to you later today.

Comment: I'm having some trouble proving 3. After using the induction hypothesis and the result from 2, I end up at  2^(2^c(3,n)) > d(n+1). Why does this hold? I know that c(3,n) > d(n) (induction hypothesis) but that's about it.

Comment: $2^\left(2^{d(n)}\right)=2^{d(n+1)}>d(n+1)$ since $2^m\gt m$ for any number $m$.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you for your help.

Comment: While trying to solve the exercise you mentioned I get stuck at $c(3, n+1) > 2^{(2^{g(n)})}$, where $g$ is the function that builds a tower of $2y+2y$ copies of $2$. Am I right in assuming that $2^{(2^{g(n)})} = g(n+1)$?

Comment: Yes, $2^{2^{g(n)}} = g(n+1)$, where $g(n)$ is tower of $2y+2$ copies of 2,  $\underbrace{2^{2^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^2}}}}}_{2y+2 \text{ copies of }2}$